# Software for taxonomic assignment?

Tags: blast, metagenome, taxonomy

I have a couple of hundred bacterial sequences of 2-30 genes of interest each, recovered from metagenomics. None of them encode rRNA. Normally I'd just BLAST the one gene I already know to be reliable phylogenetic marker, where present, but the scale of my current dataset makes it a bit daunting.

Is there any software for taxonomic assignment that you could recommend? It's fine if it requires command line use. There are so many options listed online that I didn't even know where to start... Please and thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could take a look at [kraken2](https://ccb.jhu.edu/software/kraken2) It should fit your purpose.

Comment: yes, kraken2 performed well in an independant benchmark https://lemmi.ezlab.org/

Comment: It does work well, but it's less accurate at lower taxonomic ranks (as most tools are)

Answer (score 3):

If you like blast, maybe you can try [DIAMOND](https://uni-tuebingen.de/fakultaeten/mathematisch-naturwissenschaftliche-fakultaet/fachbereiche/informatik/lehrstuehle/algorithms-in-bioinformatics/software/diamond/) - the authors claim it's much faster than BLAST.